# How to match or list exactly using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

```
Pattern: ^(?!test|abc).*$
```

I do not want to match test or abc only, but this also matches test123

What do I need to add to make it stop at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the end anchor in the lookahead as well:

```
^(?!(?:test|abc)$).*$
```

Then, it will not match `test` and `abc` as whole strings, but will match `test123`.

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQ5bG2/1) (using PCRE engine since it will work the same in a .NET one with this expression).

To apply the `$` end-of-string anchor to both `test` and `abc`, you will need to group them, I suggest using a non-capturing group for that (or use a capturing one with `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`).

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't get the syntax correct for the life of me! I'll accept in 12mins